# How do I list all active ETW sessions with their output locations, maybe in Powershell?

Tags: etw

***Question:*** How can I see all open ETW sessions, including their root paths? I'd expect some PowerShell command like [Get-EtwTraceSession](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/eventtracingmanagement/get-etwtracesession?view=win10-ps), but I don't see any.

***Background***

I work with EventTracing API, and occasionally find myself out of sessions because of stuff installed on my machine.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50232170/552510) tells me I can run `logman -ets` to see the list of sessions, and then `logman stop <SessionName> -ets` to stop some sessions. That's good, but how can I know what a cryptically-named session is?

I can tediously query individual sessions, and get a clue from their root path:

```
> logman -ets SensorFramework-{c4eaa67d-dd9a-4fce-0002-000000000000}
(...)
Root Path:            C:\windows\CCM\SensorFramework  <<<< Aha! CCM = System Center Configuration Manager
```

But I'm looking for a more convenient solution.

Comment: The very answer you cross-link to mentions that [there are PowerShell cmdlets for ETW managment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/eventtracingmanagement/?view=win10-ps).

Comment: There are, like `Get-EtwTraceSession` that I mentioned, but none of those produces a list.

Answer (score 5):

Solution: Do it through WMI:

```
Get-WmiObject -Class MSFT_EtwTraceSession -Namespace ROOT/Microsoft/Windows/EventTracingManagement `
| sort -Property LocalFilePath `
| ft -AutoSize -Property Name,LocalFilePath
```

Note: This only sometimes works (don't know what determines when), and sometimes only shows one session - `Circular Kernel Context Logger`. When not working, the `Get-EtwTraceSession` also shows only this session, presumably because it uses the same WMI object underneath.